# 5 fold Cross validation with equal Classes

Tags: cross-validation

I have 5379 observations in a data set.
Its a classification problem where the no. of bad's is 25 and the no. of goods is 5354.
I want to do a 5 fold cross validation in which 5 classes will consist of 5 bad's respectively and the no. of goods distributed equally. How do i make the split?!!!

Comment: You are thinking of stratified CV. In R there are functions that do it, what is your language of choice?

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what you are trying to accomplish? Can't you just divide both your positive and negative examples into 5 equally large sets each and then combine them into 5 cross-validation sets?

Comment: As already said, you seem to be asking about stratified cross-validation, but another question is if using only negative 5 observations per validation set would give you meaningful results.

Comment: Hi Tim, I know its very difficult to get meaningful results with 5 bad's in each cluster. Still i just need to see if anything good i can get.

Answer (score 0):

There are few methods to handle such imbalanced data. **Stratified sampling** will not help you in your case, because of large variation. Best is to augment some data using **SMOTE**. It use graph network, to augment the data in smart way. Give it a try.

Another you can try sampling technique, by considering over and under sampling technique. Using oversampling methods, we can repeat the sample with less instances, whereas with under-sampling, we loss some data of many instances.
For more, you can [refer](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/03/imbalanced-classification-problem/)